# i need to apply Fade in /fade out on my table

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have my [table](http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/22/) with toggles  on click. I would need to apply the fade in and fade out when i click on *fondos* or *sociedades*. Now it's not so smooth. How can i achieve it?

Comment: use `.animate()` (http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can add several effects, check their examples.

Comment: There is no fade anywhere in your code.

Comment: Remember to [up vote and accept](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12410058/144665).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Replace `.toggle()` with `.fadeToggle()`.

```
$(".fondos").on('click', function() {
    $("tbody .f").fadeToggle();
});

$(".sociedades").on('click', function() {
    $("tbody .s").fadeToggle();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/SPV63/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the time to animate the toggle as arguments (a number like `500` or the `'slow'` and `'fast'` strings.  `.toggle` has 0 animation time by default like `.show` and `.hide`.

http://jsfiddle.net/hAv7P/23/ -- that better?